# R : identify if a date is missing between dates

Tags: r

I'm trying to identify lines with a missing date between two dates.

[image]

I want

[image]

Comment: Please share reproducible examples ( not pictures).

Answer (score 1):

Say your data frame is `df`, this should do.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(starts_with("dt_")) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), "missing")
```